# Are new quests needed to "complete" all optional quests?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

In monster hunter world, there is at least one 8*/9* optional quest which is unlocked by completing all optional quests below that * rank.

My question is, are new quests like Deviljho or Behemoth also needed to be completed to unlock this quest now?

---

I can't check for myself, as I already unlocked that quest before any new quest was added. Also I am sorry for the sparse amoun of info as I havent palying for some time and don't remember which quest was unlocked by completing all.

Comment: Are you playing on PC? I believe the PC version is short all the content from the console versions so those aren't or yet.

Comment: @Ramirez I play on PS4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quest in question is "**The White Winds of the New World**", which requires you to clear all the free quests up to Xeno'jiiva and all the assignments up to tempered Kirin. New contents like Deviljho and post-ending contents like "A Summons from Below" aren't required. (I posted that quest without dealing with Lunastra free quests.)

However, satisfying the requirement for the quest doesn't grant you the red "COMPLETE" status. To achieve the red "COMPLETE" status, you have to complete all (yes, literally) the free quests available for that rank, up to "A Visitor from Eorzea." The same also applies for the Steam version. (Note that the Contract quest from *The Witcher 3* is a special assignment, and doesn't count for the requirement.)

Bottom line, *the red "COMPLETE" mark and the requirement for "The White Winds of the New World" are separate*.